# Does a confidence interval for an estimator allow me to evaluate a hypothesis?

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval

Let's suppose I am surveying $n$ democratic citizens about whether they will vote for Candidate A or Candidate B. Let's suppose my survey yields $x$ for Candidate A and $n-x$ for Candidate B, $x \in \Bbb Z_+$. Let $p$ denote the fraction of voters who prefer Candidate A. Let's suppose I estimate $p$ by using $\hat{p} = \frac{x}{n}$. Suppose my variance is $\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})$. Suppose $H_0 : p = 0.5$ and $H_A : p \ne 0.5$.

For $n=400, x = 215$, the estimator $\hat{p} = \frac{43}{80}$ is and a 95% confidence interval of $$\frac{43}{80} - 1.96 \frac{\sqrt{1591}}{1000}<\hat{p} < \frac{43}{80} + 1.96 \frac{\sqrt{1591}}{1000}$$

$$0.48864 < \hat{p} < 0.58656$$

### My Question

Does this confidence interval tell me anything about the validity of my null hypothesis? That is, can I decide whether to accept or reject my null hypothesis based on $0.48864 < \hat{p} < 0.58656$?

Comment: Why do you need a null hypothesis in this context?

Comment: I don't know why. That's how the textbook poised it. Why wouldn't you need one? also, I feel like people misunderstood the question. My question is if the CI for an ESTIMATOR is also useful for deciding on a hypothesis?

Comment: Many surveys are conducted to *find things out,* not to test preconceptions. Thus whether one has a null hypothesis or not depends on the objective of the survey.  Since this is a textbook problem--and, as we are seeing, therefore differs from real problems--I have taken the liberty of tagging your question as such. I don't understand your objection: *every* CI is associated with an estimator, implying the duplicate *does* answer your question.

Comment: But what do estimators have to do with hypothesis testing?That's my question what does knowing my estimator is likely accurate tell me about my hypothesis if my estimator and hypothesis don't agree? 43/80 doesn't equal 0.5, so would I reject my hypothesis?

Comment: I recommend reading the answers in the duplicate thread.